# Выбор options в дублированном select2 блоке

Tags: jquery, select2

Второй день бьюсь с такой проблемой - после клонирования строки, содержащей блок `select2` с какой-либо выбранной опцией в новом блоке отсутствует возможность повторного выбора этой опции. Все опции вбиваются в `select` из базы при помощи PHP.

После выбора и клонирования пытался отыскать нужный `option` таким способом

```
newEntry.find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected').attr('[aria-selected=false]')
```

Но, увы, результатов это не дало.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".entry").children("select").select2({});
  $(".btn-add").click(function() {
    $(".entry")
      .children("select")
      // call destroy to revert the changes made by Select2
      .select2("destroy")
      .removeAttr('data-live-search')
      .removeAttr('data-select2-id')
      .removeAttr('aria-hidden')
      .removeAttr('tabindex');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var Count = $('.entry').size();

    var controlForm = $('.controls fieldset:first-child'),
      currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
      newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone(true)).appendTo(controlForm);

    var SplitVar = (newEntry.find('select').attr('name')).split('-');
    Count > SplitVar[1] ? newEntry.find('select').attr('name', 'Mark-' + ++Count) : newEntry.find('select').attr('name', 'Mark-' + ++SplitVar[1]);

    newEntry.find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected').attr('[aria-selected=false]');

    newEntry.find('input').val('');
    controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
      .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
      .html('<div id="rectangle"></div>');

    $(".entry").children("select").each(function() {
      $(this).select2({});
    });

  }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e) {

    $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".entry").children("select").each(function() {
      $(this).select2({});
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="entry input-group col-xs-3">
      <input class="name" type="text" name="name[]">
      <select class="select-1 select-block" name="Mark-1">
        <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''>Выберите марку</option>
        <?php foreach ($Marks as $value):?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value['id_M']?>">
          <?php echo $value['MarkName']?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
      </select>
      <input class="time" type="number" name="cost[]" size="6">
      <div class="btn-add">
        <div id="cross"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Вопрос - каким способом можно в новом блоке обнулить (или перезаполнить?) все опции, чтобы их можно было повторно выбрать?

Буду благодарен за любые подсказки!

UPD: неужели никто не сталкивался с подобной проблемой и никто не знает как ее решить?

Comment: А это `.select2({})` шо такое?

Comment: При помощи этого кода происходит инициализация плагина select2, который устанавливается поверх обычного select. В скобках { } указываются его свойства (сейчас их убрал, дабы код был более читабельным).

Comment: А переинициализировать select2 пробовали?

Comment: не вижу у вас класса с таким именем `entryDet`

Comment: @ДанилЧугаев конечно, это в приведенном коде присутствует, в месте, где идет перебор при помощи each.

Comment: @Vladimir прошу прощения, это моя опечатка при выкладывании кода сюда. Спасибо за указание на ошибку.

Comment: у `jquery` нет метода `.size()` может вы имеете ввиду `length`?

Comment: @Vladimir изначально пробовал использовать `length`, но при этом у меня была ошибка (не вспомню какая), поэтому попробовал использовать `size()`, который прекрасно справился с задачей.